# How should RESTful api handle tuple query string parameters?

Tags: rest, http, get, query-string

I am implementing a GET endpoint. The endpoint needs to take a list of tuple parameter. Assume that I have an endpoint which takes name and age parameter and do some filtering;

```
GET /users?name=jack&age=30
```

But, the endpoint needs to support multiple tuple parameters. Keep in mind the age parameter is optional. Such as;

```
jack,30
matt,23
harry,NONE
mary,27
...
```

I am planning to do something like below. But not sure if it is the right approach or not.

```
GET /users?nameAgeFilters=name:jack age:30,name:matt age:23...
```

(Note: Space and semicolumns will be encoded)

Does it okay to do such things? Otherwise, what is the suggested approach for this?

Comment: I don't think it would be bad to do this, as long as your application stays consistent in the way it handles such queries in the URL. You could also opt for sending an array of names and an array of ages where all elements at index 0 are grouped together, and all elements at index 1, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what the client is capable of. You could use `JSON`:

```
[{"name":"jack", "age":30},{"name":"matt", "age":23}]
```

then `base64` encode it and send it to the server:

```
GET /users?nameAgeFilters=R0VUIC91c2Vycz9uYW1lQWdlRmlsdGVycz0=
```

then decode it in the request handler and iterate the `JSON` array.

pseudocode:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(base64decode(nameAgeFilters));
JSONArray filters = jsonObj.getJSONArray("");
iterate...
```

Comment: It was interesting answer, but it's not standard I think.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it okay to do such things?

Yes.  It's just an identifier, you can use any spelling you like.

A reason to care which spelling convention you use: will it be easy for the client to discover the URI pattern and construct the URI they need?  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` key value pairs are an excellent choice when you care about HTML clients, because HTML Forms have built into them semantics for passing precisely this information to the clients.

The generalization of the HTML form approach is a [URI Template](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570).  The specification describes a number of different encodings for key/value pairs that should be supported at Level 4.

Answer (score -1):

If age parameter is optional you can use null control with @QueryParam. For example

```
@GET
@Path("/users")
public Response getUsers(
    @QueryParam("name") String name,
    @QueryParam("age") int age
) {
    if(age!=0){
       //with age parameter stuffs
    } else{
       //without age parameter stuffs
    }
    return Response.status(200).entity("").build();
}
```